# PureScript - How to reload a module in psci?

Tags: purescript

Is there a way to reload a module or all modules in PureScript's REPL? If I make a change to a module, I've got to `:quit` and then `import` all the modules I'm working with each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:r` or `:reset`, but you would still need to import modules again. We have plans to try to make that simpler, by allowing PSCi configuration files with a default set of imports to use on load.

Another option is to define your own module with the reexports that you need. Then you only need to do a reload followed by one import.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Phil.